# understanding the concept of amounts with regex

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I am aware that regex does not work with numeric values,  yet, how can we have a regex pattern to differentiate between numbers in a google sheets formula?

for example: >=13 and <13

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  | **desired result** |
| 5 | 5♥ |
| 2 | 2♥ |
| 13 | 13♦♦♦ |
| 12 | 12♥ |
| 30 | 30♦♦♦ |
| 17 | 17♦♦♦ |
| 0 | 0♥ |
| -4 | -4♥ |
| -12 | -12♥ |
| 22 | 22♦♦♦ |
| -55 | -55♥ |
| 31 | 31♦♦♦ |
| -13 | -13♥ |
| -31 | -31♥ |

[image]

I can solve this in alternative ways like:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE("" & A2:A16,
 "\b(^" & JOIN("$|^", SEQUENCE(13, 1, )) & "$)\b", "$1♥"),
 "(^-\d+)", "$1♥"),
 "(\d+$)", "$1♦♦♦"))
```

[image]

...but I feel there could be some more "regexy" solution.

rules of combat:

- regex pattern
- no `IF`-statements
- `>=13` add ♦♦♦
- `<13` add ♥
- no `IFERROR` pivots
- no non-regex solutions

Comment: What do you mean by "yet"? There is no way for a simple string pattern matching mechanism to acquire knowledge of arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first add the diamonds and then replace those by a heart when the number is less than 13:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1 & "♦♦♦"; "^(-\d+|1[0-2]|\d)♦♦♦$"; "$1♥")
```

The regular expression looks for three patterns:

- `-\d+`: any negative number
- `1[0-2]`: 10, 11 or 12
- `\d`: 0,1,2,..., or 9.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), "^(-\d+|[0-9]|1[0-2])$", "$1♥"), "^([^♥]+)$", "$1♦♦♦")
```

[image]